# Show wordpress content only if verified with google

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, google-apps

For my wordpress, I would like my users to be automatically redirected to the google app login to see the entire content.

I found the plugin Google Apps Login, and it's working fine, but users have to be registered Wordpress Users, and it's a kind of membership plugin.

I don't want them to be registered inside the wordpress. I just want to check if the gmail address is one of our organisation on Google App.

I also found this https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate, to create the authentication myself, but I read that it's highly recommended to use a plugin for that kind of usage.

How would you do that ?